# ionic tabs app that is having issues with setRoot and Push

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, view

I have an ionic tabs app that is having issues with its views. In addition to 4 tab pages, I also have several generated pages for login, register, update profile and addtodo. I have the

```
rootPage:any = 'LoginPage';
```

in the app.component.ts and then when you click on the login() function in the login.ts module, I have

```
await this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);
```

Once the user is logged in and taken to the TabsPage the url is: http://localhost:8100/#/login

From here everything works correctly. I have a signOut() function:

```
 signOut(){
  this.afAuth.auth.signOut().then(res => {
  this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
 });
 }
```

This signs the user out, but since the Tabs are still displayed at the bottom I used

```
 window.location.reload()
```

to refresh the page and then it all looks correct.

The issue arises when the user clicks the "update profile" button on home page, which uses this function

```
    updateProfile(){
    this.navCtrl.push('ProfilePage');
    }
```

And the user is sent to http://localhost:8100/#/home/profile where they can update their profile. Then when you return to the homepage the url is still http://localhost:8100/#/home/profile and when you trigger the SignOut() function you are taken to http://localhost:8100/#/profile and it is displayed as a setRoot view for some reason.

Mainly, I am looking for a way to override all of this and make it so that when the signOut() function is triggered it simply returns the user to the rootPage, which is the 'LoginPage'.

I apologize for run on sentences and grammar errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this code to your constructor in the app.component.ts file. You'll have to import firebase and angularfire2/auth into the app.component.ts file as well.

```
   import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
   import * as firebase from 'firebase';


        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if (user) {
                this.rootPage = ProfilePage
            } else {
                this.rootPage = LoginPage
            }
        })
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged

onAuthStateChanged is an observer which is triggered everytime a user signs in or signs out.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the app.component.ts page to get rootPage refer. So, you can do like this:

```
import {appName} from '../../app/app.component';
 ...
 constructor(private app: appName) {}

 clickNewPage(newPage: string) {
   this.app.rootPage = newPage;
}
```